# Trying to restrict math.pow value upto 4 decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimalformat

I am trying to restrict value up to 4 decimal for `Math.Pow((Density * 10), -12)`

where `double Density = 0;` is defined as variable

now if `Density=7;`
then `Math.Pow((Density * 10), -12)` calculate as  `7.22476158090089E-23`
but I want it like `7.2247 E-8`.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example, `7.22476158090089E-23` is not close to `7.2247 E-8` - is that a typo? `7.2247 E-8` is 15 orders of magnitude lager than `7.22476158090089E-23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the decimal precision to 4 decimal places you can use the [Exponential Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#exponential-format-specifier-e), specifying the number of decimals to display `"E4"`:

```cs
var answer = Math.Pow(70, -12);
var displayVal = string.Format("{0:E4}", answer);
// output
7.2248E-023
```

Note that

> The exponent always consists of a plus or minus sign and a minimum of
> **three** digits.

---

However, you can use the [General Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#general-format-specifier-g) which

> If scientific notation is used ... **The exponent contains a minimum
> of two digits**. This differs from the format for scientific notation
> that is produced by the exponential format specifier, which includes a
> minimum of **three** digits in the exponent.

You will need to use `G5` to produce 5 significant digits:

```cs
var answer = Math.Pow(70, -12);
var displayVal = string.Format("{0:G5}", answer);
// output
7.2248E-23
```

Comment: how to represent the output which you show as 7.2248E-23

Comment: I've updated my answer - you can use `string.Format("{0:G5}", answer)` instead @Shivam

Comment: thx a lot one more thing if  can explain how can we show the output which you shown in  X.XXXXE-12 format where X is digit

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean @Shivam. Maybe you mean this - given : `double density = 7; int multiple = 10; int power = -12;` then to display: `string.Format("{0:0.0000}E{1}", density*multiple, power);` outputs `70.000E-12`?

Comment: thx a lot one more thing if  can explain how can we show the output which you shown in  X.XXXXE-12 format where X is digit  i mean  like any random digit  2.3456E-12 i didn't mean 2.2222E-12